# A perfectly round and optimal version of Antoine’s necklace

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

Suppose we wish to construct a round "necklace" whose links are congruent solid tori, each similar to the toroidal tube containing the necklace (see drawing below). The tube, hence each of the links as well, should be a geometric torus, that is, a solid swept by a circular disk revolved about a line coplanar with the disk and disjoint from it.

**Question:** Under the above conditions, what is the minimum number of links, and what should be the ratio between the inner radius of the tori and the radius of the torus’ hole to allow for the minimum number of links? In my estimate, the minimum number of links should be about twenty.

**Motivation:** By iteration, as in the definition of the Antoine’s necklace (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntoinesNecklace.html , in this way one would obtain a highly symmetric, perfectly round, self-similar fractal version of this wild Cantor set embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The requirement of minimum number of links is for optimal simplicity of construction.

[image]

Comment: Your guess looks good. My pocket calculator says 9.35 links of each type, and 10 is next integer. You only have to show that for a tight necklace the ratio between inner and outer radius is exactly 2. This should be an exercise in elementary geometry. Then the scaling factor should be a bit more than 4 (which I haven't computed explicitly).

Comment: I can’t say I totally have a handle on it, but your picture shows half the little link tori with the same equator as the large one. Any chance to use only 19 links but turn $10/19 \pi$ (rather than $10/20 \pi$) between links?

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: Perhaps so... But you see that this would require a larger hole, which would tighten the room inside the tube, so I don't know.